# Self-similar solution of the momentum equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

I have used the steam functions $u = \psi_{y}$ and $v = -\psi_{x}$ to transform the momentum equations to the following form
$$\rho\left(\psi_{y}\psi_{xy} - \psi_{x}\psi_{yy}\right)=-p_{x}+\mu\left(\psi_{xxy}+\psi_{yyy} \right) $$
$$\rho\left(-\psi_{y}\psi_{xx} + \psi_{x}\psi_{xy}\right)=-p_{y}+\mu\left(\psi_{xxx}+\psi_{xyy} \right) $$

I eliminated the pressure term via cross-differentiation and have obtained the final form of the equation to be as follows
$$\rho\left(\psi_{y}\left(\psi_{xyy}+\psi_{xxx} \right) - \psi_{x}\left(\psi_{yyy}+\psi_{xxy} \right) \right) = \mu\left(\psi_{xxxx} +\psi_{yyyy} + 2\psi_{xxyy} \right)\tag{1}, $$
which can be rewritten with $\nabla = \left<\partial_{x},\partial_{y} \right>$ as follows
$$\rho\left(\psi_{y}\nabla^{2}\psi_{x} - \psi_{x}\nabla^{2}\psi_{y} \right) = \mu\nabla^{4}\psi$$

Now, this is a leading edge problem of a fluid flowing over a flat plate with viscous forces dominating. The self-similar variable was found to be 
$$\eta = \frac{y}{x}\tag{2},$$
and the self-similar stream function has the following form
$$f(\eta) = \frac{\psi}{Ux}.\tag{3} $$

Substituting $(2)$ and $(3)$ into $(1)$ transforms the PDE to an ODE a follows
$$\left(1+\eta^{2}\right)^{2}f_{\eta\eta\eta\eta}+8\eta\left(1+\eta^{2}\right)f_{\eta\eta\eta} + 4\left(1+3\eta^{2}\right)f_{\eta\eta} + Re\left[2\eta ff_{\eta}+\left(1+\eta^{2}\right)\left(ff_{\eta\eta\eta} + f_{\eta}f_{\eta\eta}\right)\right]=0,\tag{4}$$
where $Re=\frac{\rho Ux}{\mu}$

Could someone please show me how this transformation is done.
I tried proceeding via the chain rule and was able to compute all the derivatives but failed to obtain the final form as shown in $(4)$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I guess your $\psi_{y} \nabla^{2} \psi_{x}-\psi_{x} \nabla^{2}$ should be $\psi_{y} \nabla^{2} \psi_{x}-\psi_{x} \nabla^{2}\psi_y$, and I guess $\nabla^2$ is the Laplacian(not the Hessian). Is your question about using $(2)$ and $(3)$ to get $(4)$?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thank you for pointing out that, have edited the question. Yeah, it's about using (2) and (3) in (1) to get (4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I have been able to obtain the answer. After terribly failing to manually compute the derivatives (since it's terribly taxing), I turned to mathematica and was successful in churning out the answer via a small program.

> eta = y/x;
>
> psi = f[[$\eta$][x, y]]*O*x; \\Using 'O' instead of velocity 'U' since mathematica realizes 'U' as a function
>
> a = D[psi, {x, 3}] + D[psi, x, {y, 2}]; \\Computation of $\psi_{xxx}+\psi_{xyy}$
>
> a2 = D[psi, y]*a; \\Computation of $\psi_{y}\left(\psi_{xxx}+\psi_{xyy}\right)$
>
> b = D[psi, {y, 3}] + D[psi, y, {x, 2}]; \\Computation of $\psi_{yyy}+\psi_{yxx}$
>
> b2 = D[psi, x]*b; \\Computation of $\psi_{x}\left(\psi_{yyy}+\psi_{yxx}\right)$
>
> c = D[psi, {x, 2}, {y, 2}]; \\Computation of $\psi_{xxyy}$
>
> H = D[psi, {y, 2}, {x, 2}]; \\Computation of $\psi_{yyxx}$
>
> P = $\nu$[D[psi, {x, 4}] + D[psi, {y, 4}]]; \\Computation of $\psi_{xxxx}+\psi_{yyyy}$
>
> L = $\nu$[c + H]; \\Computation of $\psi_{xxyy}+\psi_{yyxx}$
>
> K = P + L; \\Computation of $\psi_{xxxx}+\psi_{yyyy}+\psi_{xxyy}+\psi_{yyxx}$
>
> m = a2-b2; \\Computation of $\psi_{y}\nabla^{2}\psi_{x}-\psi_{x}\nabla^{2}\psi_{y}$
>
> Derivative[n_, 1][$\eta$][x, y] := D[eta, y]; \Replacing the functional forms with the actual derivatives of eta.
>
> Derivative[1, n_][$\eta$][x, y] := D[eta, x];
>
> Derivative[1, 1][$\eta$][x, y] := D[eta, x, y];
>
> Derivative[2, n_][$\eta$][x, y] := D[eta, {x, 2}];
>
> Derivative[n_, 2][$\eta$][x, y] := D[eta, {y, 2}];
>
> Derivative[2, 2][$\eta$][x, y] := D[eta, {x, 2}, {y, 2}];
>
> Derivative[3, n_][$\eta$][x, y] := D[eta, {x, 3}];
>
> Derivative[n_, 3][$\eta$][x, y] := D[eta, {y, 3}];
>
> Derivative[3, 3][$\eta$][x, y] := D[eta, {x, 3}, {y, 3}];
>
> Derivative[4, n_][$\eta$][x, y] := D[eta, {x, 4}];
>
> Derivative[n_, 4][$\eta$][x, y] := D[eta, {y, 4}];
>
> Simplify[m - K]

This program churns-out an output in terms of $x's$ and $y's$ and realizing that $y=\eta x$ & $Re=Ux/\nu$ yields the correct final expression.